# Internet connection dropped after docker start

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, docker

I have  Ubuntu 16.04 and every time I start a docker container and my internet connection gets dropped.

I think, there is conflicts with ip addresses or ports docker containers and internet connection. But maybe I am wrong. How can I solve this issue?

Here is my settings:

**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0;interface-name:vmnet*;interface-name:vboxnet*;interface-name:br-2164968a2156;interface-name:veth*;
```

**nmcli dev** shows

```
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
br-913cc3bb855c  bridge    connected     br-913cc3bb855c    
enp3s0           ethernet  connected     Wired connection 2 
wlp2s0           wifi      disconnected  --                 
docker0          bridge    unmanaged     --                 
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl stop docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
systemctl start docker
```

Comment: Please explain **what** that code is doing and **how** it solves the problem.